# Sensitivity Along Digestive Tract

Tags: human-biology, neuroscience, digestive-system, sensation, gastroenterology

Suppose you swallowed a little capsule with a blunt poker which had
some impulse of force applied every few seconds.  What would be the
sensitivity ordering (of lips, mouth, throat, esophagus, stomach,
duodenum, jejunum, ilium, colon, rectum, anus)?

Does sensitivity just fall to a minimum in the middle of the digestive
tract and increase again to the exit, or are there any other extremum
(e.g., at the ilium-colon interface) along the way?  I'm guessing
people could infer the answer by looking at the density of nerve cells
along this route, but I couldn't find any comparable scientific data
in my quick internet searches.

Comment: Let's be clear do you want only perceivable sensibility or non perceivable sensitivity?

Comment: I want perceivable sensibility. In the experiment, the person would be ranking how well he/she feels the periodic poking (and for a bonus, I might ask if it feels good or feels painful). It's still subjective, but the best experiment I could think of.

Comment: This is such an artificial scenario, I'm wondering why it would matter? Different parts of the GI tract are innervated for different things/reasons.